# Iterating json from a certain key

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm having a hard time iterating a simple JSON I have. I've done it easily in Javascript, but can't get it working with json.net in C#.
This is my JSON:

```
{
   "term0":{
      "id":"2131sd0",
      "senses":{
         "0":{
            "synonyms":{
               "0":{
                  "synonym":"that",
                  "context":""
               },
               "1":{
                  "synonym":"the indicated",
                  "context":""
               },
               "2":{
                  "synonym":"the present",
                  "context":""
               },
               "3":{
                  "synonym":"aforementioned",
                  "context":""
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "term1":{
      "id":"2131sd1",
      "senses":{
         "0":{
            "synonyms":{
               "0":{
                  "synonym":"the one",
                  "context":""
               },
               "1":{
                  "synonym":"this one",
                  "context":""
               },
               "2":{
                  "synonym":"the one in question",
                  "context":""
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And this is my c#:

```
JObject rootObject = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
foreach(dynamic a in rootObject.SelectToken("term0")["senses"]["0"]["synonyms"])
{
   Debug.WriteLine(a["synonym"]);
}
```

which is crashing. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Error:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.CSharp.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll
>   Additional information: Cannot dynamically invoke
>   method 'WriteLine' because it has a Conditional attribute

Comment: `which is crashing` Crashing with what? What error message do you get? Put it in your question.

Comment: When I try it, I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message: `Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.`

Comment: @MattBurland I got that too Matt. You have to call `a.First["synonym"]` and then you will receive the exception he described.

Comment: @Cornwell I *suspect* this to be a contrived example, but just so that you know - you can use `JToken` instead of `dynamic` here - that would alleviate your situation.

Comment: @ByteBlast Thanks. Why is First needed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is dynamic, so we cast it to an object and then call the ToString() method. For example:

```
Debug.WriteLine(((object)a.First["synonym"]).ToString());
```

Comment: I get an "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty." error

Comment: As @ByteBlast pointed out, it should be `Debug.WriteLine(((object)a.First["synonym"]).ToString());`

Comment: @MattBurland ok, thanks. I guess I should have actually tested it.